# How to get the Affected Records in VB.net 2010 with SQL?

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I'm trying to get the Affected Records but it always give me -1

Here is my code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM persons"
Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
MessageBox.Show(lrd.RecordsAffected)
```

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: RecordsAffected property return the number of rows changed/inserted/deleted; 0 if no rows were affected or the statement failed; and -1 for SELECT statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing affected in the database when you perform a SELECT statement. If you want to count the number of rows use `SELECT count(*) FROM persons` and then use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of a `ExecuteReader()`. And finally if you are really affecting something in the database with either INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE use `ExecuteNonQuery()` which will return you the number of affected rows in the database.